# Python-separate weekly date range from Sunday to next week Saturday

Tags: python

I am working on data cleaning with a data frame in Python, there is one column named datetime, I need to separate this column datetime to each week by range from Sunday to next week Saturday in python.

I cannot use:
df['Week_Number_closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['close_date']).dt.strftime('%W')
Because this code separate each week by range from Monday to Sunday, but I need to separate each week by range Sunday to next week Saturday, how to solve this problem, thank you so much. The best idea is separating each week by first start date of Sunday

Comment: can you provide sample data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: for example, this df['close_date'] has 1000 rows, for example, 2022-02-02, 2022-03-02, 2022-02-10, 2022-02-28.......... the list of datetime, I need to separate those datetime to each week, for example from 2022-04-03(sunday) to 2022-04-09(saturday) is the 15th week of year 2022, how to separate those datetime, and name them by the number of week of this year?

Comment: I have already solved this issue, and thanks

Comment: How to close it and I solved this issue